# Generating new document with class attributes removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sublimetext2

I have a document that has questions and each question's answer. I use this to generate a 'student version' that has the question but no answer. The original page (question+answer) is provided to the teacher to help with marking the student's responses.

I have been manually creating two pages...one for the teacher, one for the student, but I'm wondering if the answers are given a class (e.g. p.answer) could there be some way to generate the student version automatically, without having to find and delete each answer? I've tried using this jquery call:
        $('p.answers').remove();
And the result looks ok when you load the page. The if I save this page the answer reappears as the source code contains the answer text. I also need to make sure the answers are not hidden, as it would be too greater risk if the student could uncover the answer using html (student version must be clean of all answers to avoid cheating).

Note that these questions and answers are short answer, not multi-choice, a sample is below.

Any suggestions on best way to achieve this? Can it be automated by creating a button/trigger? Here is what I have tried.

```
    <p class=MsoNormal>What is the secret to happiness?</p>
    <p class=answer><span style='background:lime;mso-highlight:lime'>Finding inner peace with your past, your choices and your future.</span></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">$('p.answer').remove();</script>
```

I use sublime text 2...I would accept a way to even highlight all content within all .answer classes so they can then be deleted.

Comment: If you don't want answer sent to student page you need to remove them at server or cloud data source. Without knowing how you store this data your question is far too broad

Comment: @charlietfl Good point. At the moment I am creating both pages in html and then uploading.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion, but you should be filtering out the answers at the server level, rather than trying to disguise them on the page.

Obviously this could be done in any way, provided you have a server to serve documents, but if flexibility is what you are looking for, you might consider reading the questions/answers from a YAML file and spitting them out with a library like Ruby's [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I was hoping to keep the answer within confines of html, javascript/jquery, editing tricks on sublime text. If there is no way other than to use php or ruby then I'll conceed to getting some help. I guess I'm hoping there was some option that I have been overlooking... Also, I'm not trying to disguise them on the page, I'm trying to create a new page with the p.answer classes removed without me having to find and delete each one. Each page is massive (30 questions on average) and takes ages to manually find and delete each answer class

Comment: You might store them as json documents and load them asynchronously from the page.  I would do different html files for teachers and students still, with the name of the files with the answers not accessible to students.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use:

```
$('p.answer').hide();
```

Instead of:

```
$('p.answer').remove();
```